# Perl Hash with dynamic key values...Getting wiered results! Please advice

Tags: perl

I'm trying to build a hash with variable key values and the keys are same as values and then I'm trying to retreive a specific value for a specific key.here is the code and I'm getting exactly what I want.
My porblem is when I try to keep the peice of the code in a subroutine and call it from there I'm getting null! can someone expian why?

Here is the working code;

```
 my @ary = qw(apple mango orrange grape);

 my %dir;
 foreach my $list (@ary) {
    $dir{$list} = "$list";
 }

  my $file = $dir{mango};
  print("$file\n");
```

getiing the result : mango as expected:

Here is the code which is not working:
( which is in the main porgram)

```
  my %dir;

  foreach my $list ( @show ) {
     $dir{$list} = "$list";
     # print $dir{$list} . "\n";
  }

  while ( my ($key,$value ) = each %dir ) {
     print("$key -> $value\n");
  } 

  ### I'm genuinley getting the key values as expected#####

  my $file1 = $dir{apple};
  my $file2 = $dir{mango };
  print("Required files is : $file1" . "\n" . $file2 ."\n");
```

getting nothing!!!

Comment: `@ary` is not the same as `@show`. `use strict` and `use warnings` would tell you about this.

Comment: What does the array `@show` contain?

Comment: Could you show the code you actaully ran? The code you posted doesn't place anything in `@show`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is your code:

```
my @show = qw(apple mango orrange grape);

my %dir;

  foreach my $list ( @show ) {
     $dir{$list} = "$list";
     # print $dir{$list} . "\n";
  }

my $file1 = $dir{apple};
  my $file2 = $dir{mango};
  print("Required files is : $file1" . "\n" . $file2 ."\n");
```

You should get a value print out. The only time you wouldn't get anything is if your @show array is initialized with something else(no mango, no apple).